# Order of an infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, summation

How to prove that, for $0<c<1$,
$$
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} c^{\, j } \cdot j^{\, -(\frac{d}{2} +1 )} 
$$
is, for some positive constant $K$, of order $K + O( \, ( 1-c )^{\frac{d-2}{2}})$ when $d \geq 3$, $O(log(\frac{1}{1-c}))$ when $d=2$ and $O(1-c)^{-\frac{1}{2}})$ when $d=1$?
$K$

I would try by estimating $\int_{x=0}^{\infty} c^x x^{-d/2 - 1} dx$. Does the integral have the same order of the sum?

Comment: Is there a mix-up of indices $i$ and $j$? And the term for $j=0$ does not exist.

Comment: This is as $c\to 1^-?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any monotonically decreasing function $f$ on the positive half-axis you get
$$
\int_{j=2}^\infty f(x)\,dx\le \sum_{j=1}^\infty f(j)\le \int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx
$$
which should answer your question positive. However, the value of the integral seems to be different.

---

Using $$\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty  x^{t-1} e^{-x}\,dx$$ and 
$$
f(x)=c^x·x^{-\frac d2-1}
\implies 
f(t/|\ln c|)=e^{-t}·t^{-\frac d2-1}·|\ln c|^{\frac d2+1}
$$
one gets
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx = \frac1{|\ln c|}\int_0^\infty f(t/|\ln c|)\,dt=|\ln c|^{\frac d2}·Γ(-\frac d2)
$$
and
$$
\int_0^k f(x)dx\sim c^{k/2}·k^{-d/2}
$$
which for $c\to 1$ amounts to a constant depending on $k$.

However, the next order term is $O(c-1)$, which dominates the $|\ln c|^{\frac d2}=O((1-c)^{\frac d2})$ term except for $d=1$.

Comment: Is it obvious that f(x) is monotonically decreasing also when $d=1$?

Comment: I'd think yes, since $c<1$ and the exponent is $-3/2$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. When you write "the next order term" what does it refer to?

Comment: You get a constant for the evaluation at $c=1$, which is $O(1)$ for $c\to 1$, and the next order term has the next smallest power of $(1-c)$.